# Ambari Server Cannot Add New Host

Tags: hadoop, ssh, host, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am trying to get Ambari working between 2 hardware machines running the Hortonworks HDP 2.3 sandbox.

Both machines can successfully ssh into each other from the terminal without passwords. I am trying to add a new data node (server1.hortonworks.com) to Ambari on the main computer(sandbox.hortonworks.com). I can only assume that the fqdn I am using is correct since everything is working from the terminal. I can successfully

```
ssh server1
```

When adding the fqdn of server 1 to the main computer along with the private rsa key and then proceeding, it fails and says:

> Host checks were skipped on 1 hosts that failed to register.

I really do not know where to go from here to get the other host added correctly.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: hortonworks.com is your domain name?

Answer (score 0):

You can drill down to see the exact failure by clicking the red Failed text. Including that log will help us solve your issue.

Without seeing the exact failure in the logs I would guess this is most likely a DNS issue, since you're using hortonworks.com domain. Did you add entries for both servers to the /etc/hosts file on each node?

Run the following commands on each node to get the correct FQDN and IP respectively.

```
hostname -f
ifconfig
```

Once you have those values you need to add them to the /etc/hosts file on each host.

For example, if you get values:

```
sandbox:
sandbox.hortonworks.com
192.168.1.12

new node:
server1.hortonworks.com
192.168.1.13
```

Then you would need to add the following two lines to each /etc/hosts file:

```
192.168.1.12 sandbox.hortonworks.com 
192.168.1.13 server1.hortonworks.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the error messages that I see when I click failed:

========================== Creating target directory... ========================== Command start time 2016-03-03 22:38:13 Connection to server1.hortonworks.com closed. SSH command execution finished host=server1.hortonworks.com, exitcode=0 Command end time 2016-03-03 22:38:13 ========================== Copying common functions script... ========================== Command start time 2016-03-03 22:38:13 scp /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_commons host=server1.hortonworks.com, exitcode=0 Command end time 2016-03-03 22:38:14 ========================== Copying OS type check script... ========================== Command start time 2016-03-03 22:38:14 scp /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_server/os_check_type.py host=server1.hortonworks.com, exitcode=0 Command end time 2016-03-03 22:38:14 ========================== Running OS type check... ========================== Command start time 2016-03-03 22:38:14 Cluster primary/cluster OS family is redhat6 and local/current OS family is redhat6 Connection to server1.hortonworks.com closed. SSH command execution finished host=server1.hortonworks.com, exitcode=0 Command end time 2016-03-03 22:38:14 ========================== Checking 'sudo' package on remote host... ========================== Command start time 2016-03-03 22:38:14 sudo-1.8.6p3-20.el6_7.x86_64 Connection to server1.hortonworks.com closed. SSH command execution finished host=server1.hortonworks.com, exitcode=0 Command end time 2016-03-03 22:38:15 ========================== Copying repo file to 'tmp' folder... ========================== Command start time 2016-03-03 22:38:15 scp /etc/yum.repos.d/ambari.repo host=server1.hortonworks.com, exitcode=0 Command end time 2016-03-03 22:38:15 ========================== Moving file to repo dir... ========================== Command start time 2016-03-03 22:38:15 Connection to server1.hortonworks.com closed. SSH command execution finished host=server1.hortonworks.com, exitcode=0 Command end time 2016-03-03 22:38:15 ========================== Changing permissions for ambari.repo... ========================== Command start time 2016-03-03 22:38:15 Connection to server1.hortonworks.com closed. SSH command execution finished host=server1.hortonworks.com, exitcode=0 Command end time 2016-03-03 22:38:15 ========================== Copying setup script file... ========================== Command start time 2016-03-03 22:38:15 scp /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_server/setupAgent.py host=server1.hortonworks.com, exitcode=0 Command end time 2016-03-03 22:38:15 ========================== Running setup agent script... ========================== Command start time 2016-03-03 22:38:15 Host registration aborted. Ambari Agent host cannot reach Ambari Server 'sandbox.hortonworks.com:8080'. Please check the network connectivity between the Ambari Agent host and the Ambari Server Connection to server1.hortonworks.com closed. SSH command execution finished host=server1.hortonworks.com, exitcode=1 Command end time 2016-03-03 22:38:16 ERROR: Bootstrap of host server1.hortonworks.com fails because previous action finished with non-zero exit code (1) ERROR MESSAGE: tcgetattr: Invalid argument Connection to server1.hortonworks.com closed. STDOUT: Host registration aborted. Ambari Agent host cannot reach Ambari Server 'sandbox.hortonworks.com:8080'. Please check the network connectivity between the Ambari Agent host and the Ambari Server Connection to server1.hortonworks.com closed.

Comment: You should include this log in your original question. Please take a look at my answer as I believe it's still a DNS issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the error message:

Host registration aborted. Ambari Agent host cannot reach Ambari Server 'sandbox.hortonworks.com:8080'. Please check the network connectivity between the Ambari Agent host and the Ambari Server Connection to server1.hortonworks.com closed.

Note : server1.hortonworks.com is the node where Ambari agent should be installed. If you see the log files you can see that the command tries to setup Ambari Agent on server1.hortonworks.com - "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_server/setupAgent.py"

Resolution:
Please check the steps mentioned here : https://community.hortonworks.com/storage/attachments/2562-network-setup.pdf